# how I do decode buffer message with struct

Tags: python, sockets, binary, buffer

I write python socket client, but server return remaining time how to decode this structure in python.

```
    header = Buffer.from( [03, 00, 00, 00]);
    time = new Uint16Array(1);
    time[0] = remaining_time_in_sec;

    packet = Buffer.concat( [header, Buffer.from(time.buffer)]);

    this.socket.write(packet);
```

this function return like

```
b'\x03\x00\x00\x00\t\x01'
```

Answer (score 0):

i think solve this problem

this return binary code

```
b'\x03\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x01'

this here packet type
b'\x03\x00\x00\x00'

unpack('h',b'\x0e\x01')
return <======================
270
```